# Grep how do I check if a token comes before another in a fil?

Tags: grep

I am trying to find among a bunch of files who hold SQL statements whether we ever `SELECT` from a table before we `INSERT` into it. It seems it should be a one-liner with Grep.

I've come up with
`grep -zl "FROM (\S*).*INSERT INTO \0`

The `-z` treats the input as one line, and  then the back reference does the rest.

However testing with
`echo "SELECT a FROM x INSERT INTO x VALUES(1);" | grep -zl "FROM (\S*).*INSERT INTO \0"` 
produces no result.

In fact even `echo "aa aa" | grep "(\S*) \0"` returns nothing.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is `\0` doing here? And since the pattern is POSIX ERE, use `-E` option. Or maybe `grep -zl "FROM \S.*INSERT INTO"` will be enough? See https://ideone.com/UtmD6v

Answer (score 1):

First, let's solve it for `x`:

```
echo "SELECT a FROM x INSERT INTO x VALUES(1);" | grep -E "FROM (\S)*x.*INSERT INTO (\S)*x"
```

However, you may have many tables and you are interested about all of them. So, this is how you can list the table names:

```
select TABLE_NAME
from information_schema.tables;
```

Now, let's generate the grep for each table:

```
select CONCAT('sudo bash foo.sh "your script" ', TABLE_NAME)
from information_schema.tables;
```

and implement **foo.sh** as follows:

```
echo "$1" | grep -E "FROM (\S)*$2.*INSERT INTO (\S)*$2"
```

The query generates the grep for each table. Naturally, you can filter your query to a selection of tables instead and you might also need to handle cases like

```
select ... from yourschema.yourtable
```

or

```
select ... from `yourtable`
```

but start with the proof-of-concept I have given and see whether that's enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

#### `grep` solution:

Use `-P` option to use RegExp with `Perl` notation

```
grep -zPl "FROM ([[:alnum:]]+) INSERT INTO \1 VALUES"
```

#### Matching `SELECT` statement before `INSERT`, solution:

The reported problem is more complicated than described.

Assuming `SELECT` statements and corresponding `INSERT` statement are not in sequence.

For instance:

```
SELECT a FROM x1 
INSERT INTO x1 VALUES(1);
SELECT a FROM x2 
SELECT a FROM x3 
SELECT a FROM y1
SELECT a FROM x2 
INSERT INTO x3 VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO x2 VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO y1 VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO x3 VALUES(2);
SELECT a FROM y2
INSERT INTO y1 VALUES(1);
```

Only `x3` and `y1` are not matched. And there are nesting and duplicates.

We do not know ahead all table-names.

We need a `stack` data structure.
Push-in every table-name in select `select` statement (no duplicates), pull-out every table-name in `insert`.

Implemented using `gawk` (standard `awk` in most Linux machines) associative array. Screening input `SQL` file once.

##### `gawk` script: `script.awk`

```
/SELECT .* FROM / { # for each line matching RegExp "SELECT .* FROM"
  # read table name from current line
  tableName = gensub(/.*FROM[[:space:]]+([[:alnum:]]+).*/,"\\1",1);
  # push-in tableName into associative array (used as stack)
  tableNamesStack[tableName] = 1; 
}
/INSERT INTO / { # for each line matching RegExp "INSERT INTO "
  # read table name from current line
  tableName = gensub(/.*INTO[[:space:]]+([[:alnum:]]+).*/,"\\1",1);
  # if current tableName is in stack
  if (tableName in tableNamesStack) {
    # pull-out current tableName from stack
    delete tableNamesStack[tableName];
  } else {
    # current tableName is missing from stack, report and continue.
    printf ("Unmatched INSERT statement in line %d, for table %s\n", NR, tableName);
  }
}
```

##### running `script.awk`

```
gawk -f script.awk input.sql 

Unmatched INSERT statement in line 9, for table x3
Unmatched INSERT statement in line 11, for table y1
```